# How to use Pyomo decorator within a class

Tags: python, decorator, pyomo

Below is a simple Pyomo script using the decorator syntax - I would like to understand how to use this syntax within a class - in this case inside `Model`.

None-class version

```
from pyomo.environ import *

import random

random.seed(1000)

model = AbstractModel()

model.N = Param(within=PositiveIntegers)
model.P = Param(within=RangeSet(1, model.N))
model.M = Param(within=PositiveIntegers)

model.Locations = RangeSet(1, model.N)
model.Customers = RangeSet(1, model.M)

model.d = Param(
    model.Locations,
    model.Customers,
    initialize=lambda n, m, model: random.uniform(1.0, 2.0),
    within=Reals,
)

model.x = Var(model.Locations, model.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0))
model.y = Var(model.Locations, within=Binary)


@model.Objective()
def obj(model):
    return sum(
        model.d[n, m] * model.x[n, m] for n in model.Locations for m in model.Customers
    )


@model.Constraint(model.Customers)
def single_x(model, m):
    return (sum(model.x[n, m] for n in model.Locations), 1.0)


@model.Constraint(model.Locations, model.Customers)
def bound_y(model, n, m):
    return model.x[n, m] - model.y[n] <= 0.0


@model.Constraint()
def num_facilities(model):
    return sum(model.y[n] for n in model.Locations) == model.P
```

Decorator version within a class that doesn't work:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

import random

random.seed(1000)


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = AbstractModel()

        self.model.N = Param(within=PositiveIntegers)
        self.model.P = Param(within=RangeSet(1, self.model.N))
        self.model.M = Param(within=PositiveIntegers)

        self.model.Locations = RangeSet(1, self.model.N)
        self.model.Customers = RangeSet(1, self.model.M)

        self.model.d = Param(
            self.model.Locations,
            self.model.Customers,
            initialize=lambda n, m, model: random.uniform(1.0, 2.0),
            within=Reals,
        )

        self.model.x = Var(
            self.model.Locations, self.model.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0)
        )
        self.model.y = Var(self.model.Locations, within=Binary)

    @model.Objective()
    def obj(model):
        return sum(
            model.d[n, m] * model.x[n, m]
            for n in model.Locations
            for m in model.Customers
        )

    @model.Constraint(model.Customers)
    def single_x(model, m):
        return (sum(model.x[n, m] for n in model.Locations), 1.0)

    @model.Constraint(model.Locations, model.Customers)
    def bound_y(model, n, m):
        return model.x[n, m] - model.y[n] <= 0.0

    @model.Constraint()
    def num_facilities(model):
        return sum(model.y[n] for n in model.Locations) == model.P
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to help you on this, I just have a few qustions:

- do you know if the use of @model.Objective() (same for Constraint etc) is documented somewhere? I didn't know it existed, and it's awesome
- why do you want your "function rules" to be *methods* of the class? couldn't you defined them as functions within the `__init__` method?

I guess what I'm missing is the benefit of using a class in the first place. 
If you are just trying to wrap the model construction somehow, then a better approach is using a function:

```py
def create_model():
    model = AbstractModel()

    ...

    @model.Constraint()
    def some_rule_function(model):
        ...

    ...

    return model
```

**EDIT**: if you really want to wrap everything into a class:

```py
class Model:
    def __init__(self, model):
         self.model = model

    # alternative constructor:
    # def __init__(self):
    #     self.model = create_model()

    def construct(self, data):
        # get concrete model
        self.model = self.model.create_instance(data)

    def run(self, solver, **kwargs):
        with pe.SolverFactory(solver) as solver:
            solver.solve(self.model, **kwargs)

    def construct_and_run(self, data, solver, **kwargs):
        self.construct(data)
        self.data(solver, **kwargs)

    # other behavior you want to add to the class
```

example usage:

```py
model = Model(create_model())
```

Comment: There is not much documentation around the use of decorator with pyomo however this example if coming from pyomo/examples/pyomo/p-median/decorated_pmedian.py on the pyomo github repository. The idea of using a class is to have a sort of wrapper for the model. I think my question goes beyond pyomo to more a general guidance on how to use a decorator within a class. Can the `create_model` method be part of  the `Model` class itself in your example?

Comment: you have two choices: one is subclassing `AbstractModel` (which I don't recommend), the other is to have the `__init__` method of your class do what `create_model` does above, and still set `self.model = model` at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the logic - My thinking was that I will wrap the full model, constraints, etc. into a class so I can instantiate it simply bypassing all the data and call a `run` method. This would create a level of abstraction.

Comment: I chanced slightly the example above, but I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want to achieve. The "class" that wraps everything is `AbstractModel` or `ConcreteModel`, that include all the components (you can access them through `model.component_name`).
So you could just have a `run` or `main` function that creates the model first and then solves it.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer your direct question, here's something that seems to work for me. My interpretation is that since your model is called `self.model`, the decorators should also match that.

Note that I used `s` as the first argument in the constraint method definitions just to see if it worked, but it could also be `model` or whatever you want to call it.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = pyo.AbstractModel()

        self.model.N = pyo.Param(initialize=5, within=pyo.PositiveIntegers)
        self.model.P = pyo.Param(initialize=3, within=pyo.RangeSet(1, self.model.N))
        self.model.M = pyo.Param(initialize=3, within=pyo.PositiveIntegers)

        self.model.Locations = pyo.RangeSet(1, self.model.N)
        self.model.Customers = pyo.RangeSet(1, self.model.M)

        self.model.d = pyo.Param(
            self.model.Locations,
            self.model.Customers,
            initialize=lambda n, m, model: random.uniform(1.0, 2.0),
            within=pyo.Reals,
        )

        self.model.x = pyo.Var(
            self.model.Locations, self.model.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0)
        )
        self.model.y = pyo.Var(self.model.Locations, within=pyo.Binary)

        @self.model.Objective()
        def obj(s):
            return sum(
                s.d[n, m] * s.x[n, m]
                for n in s.Locations
                for m in s.Customers
            )

        @self.model.Constraint(self.model.Customers)
        def single_x(s, m):
            return (sum(s.x[n, m] for n in s.Locations), 1.0)

        @self.model.Constraint(self.model.Locations, self.model.Customers)
        def bound_y(s, n, m):
            return s.x[n, m] - s.y[n] <= 0.0

        @self.model.Constraint()
        def num_facilities(s):
            return sum(s.y[n] for n in s.Locations) == s.P
```

You would then be able to instantiate the model with `model = Model()`, though annoyingly (at least to me), all your Pyomo model components will be within the attribute `model.model` (e.g., `model.model.P`).

What I've done before to make the naming cleaner is to inherit from AbstractModel (though the other answer suggests that may not be good practice):

```
from pyomo.core.base.PyomoModel import AbstractModel

class Model(AbstractModel):
    def __init__(self):
        AbstractModel.__init__(self)

        self.N = pyo.Param(initialize=5, within=pyo.PositiveIntegers)
        self.P = pyo.Param(initialize=3, within=pyo.RangeSet(1, self.N))
        self.M = pyo.Param(initialize=3, within=pyo.PositiveIntegers)

        self.Locations = pyo.RangeSet(1, self.N)
        self.Customers = pyo.RangeSet(1, self.M)

        self.d = pyo.Param(
            self.Locations,
            self.Customers,
            initialize=lambda n, m, model: random.uniform(1.0, 2.0),
            within=pyo.Reals,
        )

        self.x = pyo.Var(
            self.Locations, self.Customers, bounds=(0.0, 1.0)
        )
        self.y = pyo.Var(self.Locations, within=pyo.Binary)

        @self.Objective()
        def obj(s):
            return sum(
                s.d[n, m] * s.x[n, m]
                for n in s.Locations
                for m in s.Customers
            )

        @self.Constraint(self.Customers)
        def single_x(s, m):
            return (sum(s.x[n, m] for n in s.Locations), 1.0)

        @self.Constraint(self.Locations, self.Customers)
        def bound_y(s, n, m):
            return s.x[n, m] - s.y[n] <= 0.0

        @self.Constraint()
        def num_facilities(s):
            return sum(s.y[n] for n in s.Locations) == s.P
```

In this case, you still instantiate as `model = Model()` but your Pyomo model components can be accessed as `model.P`.