# subclassing Pyomo model for auto-completion / type hinting

Tags: pyomo

I'm considering implementing a schema as below for one of my larger `pyomo` projects.  (Yes, I'm intentionally using `m` instead of the ubiquitous `self` for consistency in model.)  In the project the model creation / solving / post-processing are all separate modules and I'd like to be able to employ the IDE's auto-complete and type hinting on the model, which would make it quicker / more accurate to locate key variables, sets, etc. in the post-processing and tidy up the project.

I'm considering sub-classing `ConcreteModel` to do this.

**Is this a good/horrible idea?**

Are there other options for achieving this?

I've seen this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070558/how-to-use-pyomo-decorator-within-a-class) which indicates sub-classing has been considered for other reasons.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo


class MyModel(pyo.ConcreteModel):
    def __init__(m):
        super().__init__()
        m.S = pyo.Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3])
        m.x = pyo.Var(m.S)

        @m.Constraint(m.S)
        def upper_limit(m, s):
            return m.x[s] <= 5

        # ... etc.


m1 = MyModel()

# meanwhile.... somewhere else in post-processing:
def list_set_vals(m: MyModel) -> list[int]:
    return list(m.S)  # <-- auto completion available

print(list_set_vals(m1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious pitfalls with doing that (and autocompletion would certainly be a nice benefit).  `ConcreteModel` is really just semantic sugar on top of `Block`, and as long as you don't change the class / instance `ctype` (it should still return `Block`) then things like the solvers and transformations should still all work the same.

Other projects have made extensive use of subclassing `Block` (e.g., [IDAES](https://github.com/IDAES/idaes-pse)), although there the goal is to also support indexed subclasses, so the infrastructure to effect both scalar and indexed components is a little more complex.

Separately, Pyomo is way overdue on reorganizing / expanding the standard examples.  This use case strikes me as a nice one to add to the standard set -- please consider submitting it to the project.